# Location names in google maps using loops

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, loops, quotes

I'm writing a code that will plot multiple locations on a map using google's api. The coordinates, name and MMSI number is stored on an XML file and is imported in a javascript.

This is the part of code I'm talking about:

```
    for(i=0; i<x; i++)
      {
      var locations = [
        ['MMSI', 50.26835, 50.45563, 1],
        ['MMSI', 50.29435, 50.44523, 2],
        ['MMSI', 50.09399, 50.40548, 3]
       }
```

What I would like to do is add `i` to the end of `'MMSI'` and turn it into a variable which is predefined above.

So what is written above the first code is:

```
    var MMSI1 = 163474;
    var MMSI2 = 209483;
    var MMSI3 = 705245;

    etc, etc...
```

and need the map markers to display those numbers instead of simply MMSI.

But I don't know how to achieve this as the program won't run every time I try it and google's api will only work with quotes, not variables.

I'm pretty sure there is a simple answer to this question and I am sorry for having to ask such a stupid question but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere or figure it out on my own.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Also I'm sorry if I used any terms wrong I'm still learning this language and I don't always know if I'm saying things correctly.

Comment: Would you mind to set up a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your working current status so that we can help you better?

Comment: Also, where do those numbers come from (163474, 209483, 705245)?

Comment: Right now those are just random numbers but once finished they will be MMSI numbers from http://www.aishub.net/

Comment: Anyway here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/gt8vK/ not sure I did that correctly but I hope this helps.

Comment: Can I see xmlhttp.responseXML please? I mean the XML

Comment: This is all that's in it at the moment:

        <Vessels>
        <Ship>
            <MMSI>431000527</MMSI>
   <CALLSIGN>SLBM</CALLSIGN>
   <LATITUDE>35.4150</LATITUDE>
   <LONGITUDE>139.725</LONGITUDE>
   <DESTINATION>JP SGM</DESTINATION>
        </Ship>
        <Ship>
            <MMSI>244660180</MMSI>
            <CALLSIGN>PD8027</CALLSIGN>
            <LATITUDE>52.4066</LATITUDE>
            <LONGITUDE>4.82345</LONGITUDE>
            <DESTINATION>lalallal</DESTINATION>
        </Ship>
        
 </Vessels>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this seems to work, I removed your ajax call to load the XML and pasted the XML in the fiddle itself. Also, I'm not an XML guru so there might be an easier method for the first part.

http://jsfiddle.net/gt8vK/4/

```
var x= "<Vessels><Ship><MMSI>431000527</MMSI><CALLSIGN>SLBM</CALLSIGN><LATITUDE>35.4150</LATITUDE><LONGITUDE>139.725</LONGITUDE><DESTINATION>JP SGM</DESTINATION></Ship><Ship><MMSI>244660180</MMSI><CALLSIGN>PD8027</CALLSIGN><LATITUDE>52.4066</LATITUDE><LONGITUDE>4.82345</LONGITUDE><DESTINATION>lalallal</DESTINATION></Ship></Vessels>";

var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(x,'text/xml');
var allShips = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Ship");
console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Ship")[0].getElementsByTagName("MMSI")[0].childNodes[0].text)
var ships = [];

for (var i = 0, l = allShips.length; i < l; i++) {
    ships.push({
    name: 'MMSI' + (i + 1).toString(),
    originalName: allShips[i].getElementsByTagName("MMSI")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
    latitude: allShips[i].getElementsByTagName("LATITUDE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
    longitude: allShips[i].getElementsByTagName("LONGITUDE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    })   
}



        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
          zoom: 2 ,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < ships.length; i++) {
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(ships[i].latitude, ships[i].longitude),
            map: map
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(ships[i].name);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker, i));
        }
```

Basically I placed all the ships in an object, instead of creating a new variable for each one, this will keep everything cleaner and you can still access each one of them, just use ships['number'] instead of shipNumber.